# XMLHttpRequest resposta "suja de HTML"

Tags: javascript, ajax

Eu fiz 3 funções para otimizar o XMLHttpRequest:

```js
function _ (x){
 return document.getElementById(x);
}
function ajaxObj (meth, url){
 var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
 x.open(meth, url, true);
 x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 return x;
}
function ajaxReturn (x){
 if(x.readyState==4 && x.status==200){
  return true;
 }
}
```

Chamo as 3 funções dessa forma:

```js
function ativar(){
      var codigo=_("codigo").value;
      var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "verif_cad.php");
      ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
          alert(ajax.responseText);
          }
        }
      ajax.send("codigo="+codigo+"&us="+u);
 }
```

Quando utilizo html() ou innerHTML da resposta do ajax pelo ajax.responseText não tenho problema. Mas quando quero comparar a resposta com um if, ou utilizar a resposta como uma variável numérica, não funciona porque ela "parece suja de HTML" como nessa imagem obtida por alert(ajax.responseText):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu obtenho a resposta "limpa", neste caso, 48 ?

Comment: Verifica como está seu arquivo **verif_cad.php** se estiver contendo códigos **HTML** com certeza ele ira retorna esse código, caso contrário não

Comment: Deve ser algo no seu PHP.

Comment: Em verif_cad.php só tem PHP, no arquivo do Ajax que com tem HTML

Comment: Para testar, coloquei todo o javascript num arquivo separado sem tags HTML e continua com o mesmo problema.

Comment: O arquivo conexao.php estava com tags HTML! Num video tutorial o cara falou pra sempre colocar as tags HTML, mesmo em arquivos PHP para serem incluidos em outros. Até agora, nunda tinha dado problema!